# yeoman / sass import a file

Tags: compass-sass, sass, yeoman

I'm using yeoman and i want to import a native css from a bower component.

In my main.scss i'm doing the following :

`@import "../components/select2/select2.css";`

This works fine until i'm building my project.
I'm having an issue saying that my imported file is not available.

Did you faced the same issue ?  How did you fixed ?
I'm running yeoman 1.0.0-beta.3

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, are you using the newest versions?

Comment: yes last version of yeoman 1.0.0-beta.3  For me it works in dev mode but not anymore when i'm building the project 'grunt build'  I'm getting 404 in the browser

Comment: Ah, can I see your compass config please? Also the URL that it returning 404. And the URL that requests it.